# A better way to check for authorization of API requests using Express JS

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, graphql, restful-authentication

I have a super redundant server.js file, since nearly every method in it belonging to the REST API starts like that, as I have to check at the API requests whether the client is authorized to ask for the particular thing.

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

// ...

app.get('/getsomething', function(req, res) {
  "use strict";
  var token = req.headers[tokenName];
  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, app.get('some_secret'), {
      ignoreExpiration: false
    }, function(err, decoded) {
      if (err || typeof decoded === "undefined") {
        res.json({
          status: 401,
          message: "unauthorized"
        });
      }
      else { // actual code starts here...
```

What would be a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have a middleware that checks every request coming in, something like this:

```
// AUTHENTICATION
app.use(async (req) => {
    try {
        const token = req.headers.authorization
        const { person } = await jwt.verify(token, SECRET)
        req.person = person
        return req.next()
    } catch (e) {
        return req.next()
    }
})
```

In this example, both success or fail allows the user to pass through to the route, but `req.person` is only populated if the user is logged in. Keep in mind, this is an asynchronous function due to `async` keyword. It returns a promise and we are using try/catch architecture. This allows us to use `await` which halts execution until `jwt.verify()` has populated `person`. This then makes `req.person` available in every route. In this example, `person` is a property that you specified when you did `jwt.sign()` to create the JWT. Here is an example to jog your memory:

```
jwt.sign({
  person: 'some unique identifier'
}, 'secret', { expiresIn: '1y' })
```

In this way, `req.person` can only ever be populated by decoding a valid JWT. Do not be confused by `const { person } = await jwt.verify(token, SECRET)`. This is the same as writing:

```
const decodedJWT = await jwt.verify(token, SECRET)
const person = decodedJWT.person
```

In every protected route, you can simply make the first line of code something like:

```
// PROTECTED
app.get('/radical', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        // If req.person is falsy, the user is not logged in
        if (!req.person) return res.status(403).render('error/403')
        // Otherwise, the user is logged in, allow him/her to continue
        // Replace res.render() with res.json() in your case.
        return res.render('radical/template', {
            person: req.person
        })
    } catch (e) {
        return next(e)
    }
})
```

This example demonstrates EJS View Templating Engine:

- See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs

Then, **after** all your routes, put a splat route, and an error handling middleware:

```
// SPLAT ROUTE
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    return res.status(404).render('error/404')
})

// ERRORS
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(500).render('error/500')
    throw err
})
```

The error handling middleware needs to come last, and it has an additional 4th parameter which is `err` and it contains the value of the parameter of `next()` only if you pass a parameter to it, ie: `next('Error happened')`.

This above code works without any changes for GraphQL as well. To handle authentication in GraphQL, simply examine this:

```
// GRAPHQL
app.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress((req) => {
    const context = {
        person: req.person
    }
    return {
        schema,
        context,
        rootValue: null,
        formatError: (error) => ({
            message: error.message,
            locations: error.locations,
            stack: error.stack,
            path: error.path
        }),
        debug: true
    }
}))
```

The GraphQL endpoint must be mounted **after** the authentication middleware. The logged in user will be available in every resolver as `context.person`, or if the request is illegal, context.person will be falsy. I mention this for any others searching in the future.

Comment: If anyone has any questions, let me know. I will expand on any reasoning or syntax usage.

Comment: It seems to be a very nice solution and thank you for your devotion! I need some time to implement this because the concept is still new for me. I will check back a bit later and ask if something's not clear.

Comment: This is a good resource about const and let: http://wesbos.com/let-vs-const/ . It will take you some time to harness async/await because it involves promises, but you should definitely examine them. We also used destructuring which is that `const { person } =` part. Basically, there are lots of articles out there about ES6 aka ES 2015 syntax, and I think you will enjoy what you find if you start utilizing any/all of it.

Comment: So, I needed some time and I'm still learning and experimenting with it, but I already have a working instance of your code in my app and it's doing its job very well! Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear. That will treat you well and be very scalable. I recommend reading through the Express docs also now that you have it working. You will learn all kinds of little tricks. Their docs are amazing, very well put together. The sections on middlewares and error handling will show you everything I said. I recommend reading about `next()` everywhere in those docs until you feel comfortable understanding how it works. It is the perfect candidate to show you how middleware works and why we might care about higher-order components. Unrelated, but anything async/await is worth study time.

Comment: The short and dirty on what you did was create an authentication middleware that runs before every request. You could add more such as one that logs request data on every request or increases a view counter or other usage statistics every request.